# Delete node from treeView when Attribute are similar

Tags: c#, xml

Am working on my first C# Winform application :( 
I browse an XML file to a treeView , then I select node and I wante do delete it.My problem is :
Each node contains an Id attribute , then this node is used two or tree time in the same file , ans i want to delete all the duplicate .

This is an exp  :

```
<list>
<object number="3" background_colour="7" id="2996" name="MyFirst" type="2">

    <child id="3794" x="0" y="0"/>
    <child id="13794" x="0" y="44"/>
    <child **id="13794**" x="239" y="44"/>
</object>
<object height="4" id="13793" line="24487" direction="1"/>

<object height="194" **id="13794"** line_attributes="24487" line ="0"/>
</list`>
```

So, Now I can delete node ( node is an object)  , but I want if i delete the object with id =13794 , I automaticlly delete also the Child with id =13794

I really think about this from one week :(  if someone have an idea . Thanks.

My function Code :

```
  private void DeleteHandler(TreeNode tNode)
    {
        tNode.BackColor = Color.Red;
        var messageResult = MessageBox.Show("Are u sur to delete node and childs?", "Alerte de suppression", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (messageResult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
            RemoveChildNodes(tNode);
        else
            tNode.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    }


    private void RemoveChildNodes(TreeNode aNode)
    {

        if (aNode.Nodes.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = aNode.Nodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                aNode.Nodes[i].Remove();
            }
        }
        var messageResult = MessageBox.Show("Delete from XML too ?", "Alerte de suppression", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (messageResult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
            aNode.Remove();

    }

    private void deleteNode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode sourceNode = sourceTreeView.SelectedNode;
        DeleteHandler(sourceNode);
    }
```

Comment: What have you done till now and how is it not working? Update the question.

Comment: Now , a can select node and delete them , but only one node !
I want to delete all node with the same attribute value ID

Comment: Please post your code here if you need improvements. If it is confidential, anonymise it.

Comment: Done ! is the code about delete node used actually

Comment: So you want to delete from the Tree or the XML or both?

Comment: Tree and xml .. Maybe if i delete from tree then i save the new tree is a solution to delete from xml too ..

Comment: It would be easier to delete from the XML and then reload the tree. To delete from the tree you would need to use recursion or a stack. You can delete from the XML in a single line of code - see my answer below of how to delete from XML.

Comment: Yes, but how I can use your answer in my code , I will used ur function when i select the node ?

Comment: @QuenD - edited my answer below to show how you would implement with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ you could delete all nodes in the XML with a certain ID like this.

```
    private XDocument DeleteID(string XmlFile, string NodeID)
    {
        XDocument list = XDocument.Load(XmlFile);

        list.Descendants().Where(elm => (string)elm.Attribute("id") == NodeID).Remove();

        return list;
    }
```

You could then edit RemoveChildNodes to be something like:

```
    private void RemoveChildNodes(TreeNode aNode)
    {
        //get the id from the node (I don't know where id is for our purpose I'll say it is in tag
        XDocument list = DeleteID(@"c:\temp\test.xml", (string)aNode.Tag);

        //reload the tree here

        var messageResult = MessageBox.Show("Delete from XML too ?", "Alerte de suppression", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (messageResult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            list.Save(@"c:\temp\test.xml");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to do is remove all the nodes from you Tree that have the same ID. LINQ can be used to build a collection of all Nodes that have a particular ID and then you can just remove all the nodes in the list.

Sorry I haven't time at the moment to produce any code at the moment but I hope this helps.

Ok I have added some code.
Here is a quick piece of code I knocked up. Use it for an idea, I have not tested it. This will only check the top level of nodes but it wouldn't be hard to correct this.

```
IEnumerable<TreeNode> Result = TreeView.Nodes.WHERE((N) => N.ID == "13794");
foreach(TreeNode Node in Result){TreeView.Nodes.Remove(Node);}
```

Hope this helps
Danny

Comment: Is that , but the problem is I dont know how strat it ... maybe if u have time later , u can just tell me how can I start 
Thanks

Comment: That will only work if all the Nodes are at the same level (no hierarchy). You would have to walk the tree recursively to find all nodes.

Comment: I made that point in my answer Kevin. "This will only check the top level of nodes".